# How to use a parallel stream to do this function

Tags: java, java-stream

This is my solution for this function. It works but I need to use a parallel stream to do his computation faster.

```
public static List<String> findWinners(String pattern, int minLength, boolean even, Stream<String> stream){
    return stream.filter(x -> x.matches(pattern) && x.length() >= minLength).filter(x -> x.length() % 2 == (even ? 0 : 1))
            .sorted(new Comparator<String>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                    return o1.length() - o2.length();
                }
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should compile `pattern`.  Try this.

```
public static List<String> findWinners(String pattern, int minLength, boolean even, Stream<String> stream) {
    Pattern compiled = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    return stream.parallel()
        .filter(x -> compiled.matcher(x).matches() && x.length() >= minLength)
        .filter(x -> x.length() % 2 == (even ? 0 : 1))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(String::length))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Moving `Pattern.compile` out of the stream definitely is the greatest lever. And using `Comparator.comparing(String::length)` surely makes the code more readable, but as it is a performance question, you can use `comparingInt`. And since all conditions are effectively combined with `&&`, it’s worth performing the cheapest test(s) first, as it may skip the more expensive test(s). `filter(x -> x.length() >= minLength && (x.length() & 1) == (even ? 0 : 1) && compiled.matcher(x).matches())`

Answer (score 0):

You can do customization for the parallel stream using `ForkJoinPool`, by defult the parallel stream using **8 threads**, but for the huge data sometimes  it will take more times.

here you can do customization for the parallel stream :

```
public static List<String> findWinners(String pattern, int minLength, boolean even, Stream<String> stream) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    int numberOfThreads = 20;
    ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(numberOfThreads);

    List<String> winners = forkJoinPool.submit(() -> {
        return stream.parallel()
                .filter(x -> x.matches(pattern) && x.length() >= minLength)
                .filter(x -> x.length() % 2 == (even ? 0 : 1))
                .sorted(new Comparator<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                        return o1.length() - o2.length();
                    }
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }).get();
    
    return winners;
}
```

Comment: The default is not to use eight threads, but to use as many threads as you have CPU cores. Since threads don’t do magic, having more than that number of threads doesn’t improve the performance for this kind of task. Rather, it will make it slower.